# Is there a way the to secure proxy user/passwords for Vagrant configs?

Tags: vagrant

I am working through several use cases with Vagrant and have been having difficulty coming up with a good solution for handling corporate proxies in an elegant way.  In my initial Vagrantfile, I ended up with this config for apt.conf

```
user = 'me'
pwd = 'mypwd'    
config.vm.provision :shell, :inline => "echo 'Acquire::http::Proxy \"http://#{user}:#{pwd}@proxy.corp.com:3210\";' >> /etc/apt/apt.conf"
config.vm.provision :shell, :inline => "echo 'Acquire::https::Proxy \"http://#{user}:#{pwd}@proxy.corp.com:3210\";' >> /etc/apt/apt.conf"
config.vm.provision :shell, :inline => "echo 'Acquire::socks::Proxy \"http://#{user}:#{pwd}@proxy.corp.com:3128\";' >> /etc/apt/apt.conf"
```

Obviously, I want to avoid having my user/password stored in the Vagrantfile since I am planning on keeping it under version control.  My next attempt was to prompt from within the Vagrantfile using the highline plugin, but that causes the prompt to appear during every vagrant command and not just during init (when this config would apply).

Am I going about this the wrong way?  If so, what other options are available to deal with proxy configuration that fits well into the Vagrant model?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do this in the following way:

Create a file called `proxy.yml` and add it to your `.gitignore` so that it doesn't get committed.

Then inside your `Vagrantfile` you could have something like this:

```
if File.exist?("proxy.yml")
    require 'yaml'
    proxy = YAML::load(File.open('proxy.yml'))
    config.vm.provision :shell, :inline => "echo 'Acquire::http::Proxy \"http://#{proxy['user']}:#{proxy['pass']}@proxy.corp.com:3210\";' >> /etc/apt/apt.conf"
end
```

The contents of `proxy.yml` would be:

```
user: "username"
pass: "password"
```

Comment: Thanks, I've tried that approach and it seems to be working okay.  I'm considering having it prompt if the proxy.yml file doesn't but I am still debating that since I am thinking of making this part of a Continuous Integration process which would be headless.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [vagrant-proxyconf](http://tmatilai.github.io/vagrant-proxyconf/) plugin:

```
vagrant plugin install vagrant-proxyconf
```

As you probably want to use the same settings for all Vagrant VMs, you can put the configuration to *~/.vagrant.d/Vagrantfile* (which is local to your machine):

```
config.apt_proxy.http = "http://me:mypwd@proxy.corp.com:3210"
```

Apt uses by default the same proxy with HTTPS URIs too, so you shouldn't need to specify it in your case.

Other option is to pass the configuration with environment variables. For example on command line, *~/.bashrc*, etc.:

```
export VAGRANT_APT_HTTP_PROXY="http://me:mypwd@proxy.corp.com:3210"
```

The plugin can also configure proxies for the whole VM, not only for Apt.